# LiveBindings TObjectBindSourceAdapter

Tags: delphi, firemonkey, livebindings, delphi-10.4-sydney

I was playing arround with LiveBindings but I cant make TObjectBindSourceAdapter  to work. I doesn't change the properties on my object. I've also tried this [example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28281721/delphi-xe-livebindings-bits-to-byte). Same problem.

I have a FMX application, with only a checkbox on the form

Then I've made a simple class:

```
  TSettings = class
  private
    FTest: Boolean;
    procedure SetTest(const Value: Boolean);
  public
    property Test: Boolean read FTest write SetTest;
  end;

{ TSettings }

procedure TSettings.SetTest(const Value: Boolean);
begin
  FTest := Value;
end;
```

Then I've made the binding using the designer:

[image]

I've created the adapter:

```
procedure TFormMain.PrototypeBindSource1CreateAdapter(Sender: TObject; var ABindSourceAdapter: TBindSourceAdapter);
begin
  ABindSourceAdapter := TObjectBindSourceAdapter<TSettings>.Create(Self, TSettings.Create, True);
end;
```

And added an OnChangeEvent to the CheckBox:

```
procedure TFormMain.CheckBox1Change(Sender: TObject);
begin
  TLinkObservers.ControlChanged(Sender as TComponent);
end;
```

But if I set a breakpoint in `SetTest` it never gets there.

What am I missing?

The project can be downloaded [here](http://borrisholt.dk/Stackoverflow/LiveBindingsDEMO.7z)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I know this is quite weird if you have already your PrototypeBindSource AutoPost property set to True, but you have to explicitly set (start edit) the related TBindSourceAdapter (end edit) by code in your procedure TFormMain.PrototypeBindSource1CreateAdapter, with

```
ABindSourceAdapter.AutoPost := true;
```

Besides, what is your Link component class?

Comment: AutoPost  is true, and PrototypeBindSource is active. 

I've updateted the question with a lint where to download my demo project

Comment: @Jens, but it works! -> please read carefully my solution:
"..but you have to explicitly set it by code in your procedure TFormMain.PrototypeBindSource1CreateAdapter, with
*ABindSourceAdapter.AutoPost := true;*"
Actually, this is the TObjectBindSourceAdapter that you need to set to AutoPost to true, although the related TPrototypeBindSource is already AutoPost true

Comment: Tes. Thank you. I've missed that

Comment: Relatively to this, I posted an issue in Embarcadero Quality that points this possible confusion: https://quality.embarcadero.com/browse/RSP-31642